# Flutter change font color if value is negative

Tags: flutter, dart

I am showing data like this in text widget

```
Text(
  '${list[index]['give'] - list[index]['take']}',
  style: TextStyle(
      fontFamily:
      'PoppinsMedium'),
),
```

There are 3 types of value in this data Value which is positive like `10.0` Value which is neutral is `0` and value in negative which is `-10.0`

What i need to do is if value is positive or neutral so it will show font color Green and if its negative then it will show Red.

I know i have 2 double if value is +ve and -ve and 1 int when its neutral 0. Need to know is it possible i can do this ?

Answer (score 3):

Use a boolean test to set the appropriate "color" value for the TextStyle

```
Text(
  '${list[index]['give'] - list[index]['take']}',
  style: TextStyle(
      fontFamily:
      'PoppinsMedium',
      color: (yourValue < 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.green),
),
```

Obviously, replace "yourValue" with the appropriate variable value to be tested